# Depth scan of substring

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, search, count

Many times I saw some codes tagged as "Solved" with over 70 votes, but for real in every case that was the part of the solution. I have a little problem with algorithm to search (lets say)

```
stringToSearch="aa";
sourceString="aaaaaa"; // len=6
```

Most of solutions from network will return **3** occurences, what is **wrong** result cuz:

1st occurence = sourceString[0], sourceString[1]

2nd occurence = sourceString[1], sourceString[2]

3rd occurence = sourceString[2], sourceString[3]

4th occurence = sourceString[3], sourceString[4]

5th occurence = sourceString[4], sourceString[5]

Now things are getting little complicated...

Edit: The question is how to count those occurences :)

Comment: can't you just re-search starting from the last find point until the string is exhausted?

Comment: I upvoted you for that :)
I don't know how to make it fast to count all of these occurences

Comment: So I have to search for string as many times as sourceString-stringToSearch.Lenght+1?

Comment: can't you just keep calling something like this until you reach the end of the string? i = string.IndexOf("aa", i);

Comment: The Aho-Corasick string search algorithm will find all of the occurrences. "How to count" is really up to you. Are you really asking how to find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
for (int index = sourceString.indexOf(stringToSearch);
     index != -1;
     index = sourceString.indexOf(stringToSearch, index + 1)) {
  indexes.Add(index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice & short code :)

I will try later to eliminate the List I think

Can you explain why indexes.Add is in standalone brackets?